# Retrieving entered text in field (android help)

Tags: android

I have this code for a username field for an Android app.  I would like to validate the field to see if it is empty. Here is my code:

```
View a = findViewById(R.id.authentication);
(a.toString().equals(""))
```

I am guessing that you cannot use view to get the data entered by the user. What would be the best way to see if these fields are empty?

Answer (score 2):

a.toString() does not do what you think it does.

Use `TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.authentication); (a.getText().equals(""))`